# Node.js mongodb invalid _id values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, objectid

Some company code has been creating documents with `_id` values that are not valid bson `ObjectId` values.

The code that has done so looks like:

```
var collection = getTheCollection();
collection.save(
    { _id: 'questionableId', /* more values */ },
    { w: 1, fsync: true },
    function(err, result) { /* ... */ }
)
```

Of course, if `{ _id: new ObjectID('questionableId'), /* ... */ }`, was used the following error would be encountered:

```
Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
at new ObjectID (/.../mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/objectid.js:50:11)
```

Fortunately, everything seems to be working fine, with plenty of values like `'questionableId'` in `_id` properties.

Is this code acceptable? Intuitively, I'd like to introduce a new `id` property for every document which can happily store values like `'questionableId'`, and allow mongo to natively handle generating an `_id` property.

**Is my company's current code risky?**

Comment: no, mongodb generates ID for you, vs you need to generate unique id on your own

Comment: Not sure I follow. If we set a document's `_id` value manually, we can save that value to mongo even if the value we set would through an error if processed by the `ObjectID` constructor. Everything works, but I want to know if there are any concerns with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the current implementation. It's a valid choice not to use an `ObjectId` for the `_id` field and there may have been reasons why things were done this way (try to find out about the background before you consider changing things).

The [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) states:

> MongoDB reserves the _id field in the top level of all documents as a
>   primary key. _id must be unique, and always has an index with a unique
>   constraint. However, except for the unique constraint you can use any
>   value for the _id field in your collections.

Mind you, there are certain implicit features that you may or may not want to benefit from by switching to an `ObjectId`. You can, for instance, extract the creation data of any document from its `ObjectId` as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).

Also, `ObjectId` is arguably by far the most used data type for the `_id` field  and I would personally recommend using it, too.

Comment: Perfect, exactly the part of the documentation I needed to set my mind at ease!